# update_option returns false in AJAX, how to debug?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, options

I tried debug plugins for WordPress, but they only show the current page SQL queries. How to debug if `update_option` returns false?

I am updating an object decoded from AJAX request with `json_decode` although I doubt it has anything to do with it.

Comment: it would be helpful to see code, something we can test, or anything....

Comment: Can you add the code where you register your ajax request handlers, the ajax function code and also the script where you actually call the action function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my settings where filtered by validation function registered by `register_setting`. Somehow I thought that it would only affect settings that where going through wordpress's own settings fields and not a custom AJAX function (the way I have it setup).

To the point of the question: I used `php` `exit` to debug the AJAX. `update_option` returned false because the options fields where the same after validation (I was missing out one particular setting)